# The GitHub.app for Mac crashes every time, if a local repository is loaded

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

If I open a local repository the GitHub.app for Mac crashes. But only if I click on the tab 'Changes'.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: You have to be sure that all folders in your repository are readable.

I had a folder in my repository, which was not readable. After I granted read-access the GitHub.app didn't crash anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have large files in the local repository. I believe github was crashing because in my local repository I had a 13MB pgm image. The issue was solved by removing the large image file from the directory.

Comment: I'm experiencing this too.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that Mac GitHub marked "Responder Train (185)" in "GitHub | About GitHub" will sit and beach ball for a significant period of time if you have previously added repositories that exist on another machine and which were mounted over CIFS, but whose mounts are not currently available.

Eventually, GitHub for Mac will start and will mark the repos it couldn't read as unavailable. Alternately, just make sure you establish all the CIFS-mounted repositories and GitHub will start up immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix a similar issue by editing my `.git/config` file. (Changed to `remote = origin`)

See: [GitHub for Mac crashes on open because of local repository issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664985/github-for-mac-crashes-on-open-because-of-local-repository-issue)