# GitHub for Mac crashes on open because of local repository issue

Tags: macos, git, github

I am trying to figure out why my GitHub for Mac crashes on start when I choose a local repository. I added this local repository from a folder I had cloned. Unfortunately, I was playing around with the git command line and I must have done something to corrupt the local repository.

Now my GitHub for Mac is trying to access this corrupted repository on reopen and I can't change it within the program before it crashes. I would rather not purge the system of files because I have other repositories saved in GitHub for Mac.

How exactly would I be able to solve this issue or delete the reference to this local repository that is causing me massive issues? I have attempted to get an answer from the people at GitHub but they have not responded to me yet. Thank you. The error I am getting is below.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Received error from <RACDynamicSignal: 0x600000e3dca0> name:  in binding for key path` "headerContentViewModel" on <GHChangesViewModel: 0x600000129420>: 
NSError { domain: GTGitErrorDomain, code: -12, description: "Failed to create reference to tracking branch from <GTBranch: 0x600000e20c00> name: refs/heads/master, shortName: master, sha:   
b5db93cacaf51cde5ad27c605c4bdb114cd23605, remoteName: (null), repository: <GTRepository: 0x60000041b4e0> fileURL: file:///Users/name/Desktop/personalWebsite/", underlying error: NSError { domain: 
GTGitErrorDomain, code: -12, description: "'https://github.com/name/git.git' is not a valid remote name." } }'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSExceptionabort() called
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The GitHub.app for Mac crashes every time, if a local repository is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179058/the-github-app-for-mac-crashes-every-time-if-a-local-repository-is-loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've changed the config file, specifically for the repo location. If you're not able to repair the git config file yourself, can you do `cat ./.git/config` for us?

Comment: Thank you. I just had no idea where to look. I was looking in the GitHub for Mac files instead of that repository's configuration files.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, the source turned out to be an incorrect line in my .git/config file.

The master branch had these lines:

[branch "master"]
    remote = git@github.com:/.git

which matched most of the url value for the [remote "origin"] line.

Changing the line to this:

```
remote = origin
```

Fixed the problem immediately, and no more "Unable to create tracking branch" errors like I've had for quite some time.

Be sure to make a copy of that line in case it doesn't work.

GitHub support verified that this was the correct solution - at least in my case.

Comment: Thank you!  Changing:
 
   `remote = [repo_github_url]`

to

   `remote = origin`

fixed this problem for me!